# Not able to retrieve properties values from a activeMq message

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

```
    ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, 
    messageId = null, originalDestination = null, 
    originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, 
    destination = null,    
    transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, 
    brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = whyMe, 
    replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0,  
    roupID = null, 
    groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false,  
    userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null,   
    dataStructure = null, 
    redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {PARAM1=xsd@1234, 
    PARAM0=testme, TYPE=ADMIN}, readOnlyProperties = false, 
    readOnlyBody  = 
    false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = 
    LOGIN_REQUEST#1}
```

I want to retrieve the values of the properties PARAM0 and PARAM1
I was using the following snippet , but it's returning me a blank values. Kindly help.

Kindly note :- message is of type ITextMessage.

Comment: This is a very low quality question, kindly elaborate on what your have tried, what you want to achieve what client or language you are using etc.

Comment: Looks like you are using the NMS library (ITextMessage). See the samples, in the code. There are methods for retrieving property values in the API.

Answer (score 1):

you have to access properties http://activemq.apache.org/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/P_Apache_NMS_IMessage_Properties.htm